# nested vector of maps how to get values

Tags: clojure

```
{:measure-value-sets (
   {:benchmark "EUR.EONIA.6Y", :bvalue "0"}),
 :dimensions (
   {:type "Currency", :dvalue "EUR"} 
   {:type "ValueUnderlying_0", :dvalue "21.59999999999811"})}

{:measure-value-sets (
   {:benchmark "EUR.6M3M.5Y6M", :bvalue "-0"}), 
 :dimensions (
   {:type "Currency", :dvalue "EUR"} 
   {:type "ValueUnderlying_0", :dvalue "13.199999999998733"})}

{:measure-value-sets (
   {:benchmark "EUR.LIBOR.U4", :bvalue "0.03558586"}), 
 :dimensions (
   {:type "Currency", :dvalue "EUR"} 
   {:type "ValueUnderlying_0", :dvalue "99.76045398474537"})}

... snip...
```

I have a dataset similar to above, i need to get the values for benchmark, bvalue, dvalue can someone advise the best way to iterate over these and kill the values?

Comment: There are 2 `:dvalue` for each map , which one do you want? Also I understand your code above is a vector of these maps, correct?

Comment: The dataset is not valid Clojure. The inner lists are not quoted, and should probably be vectors instead. By "kill" do you mean remove?

Comment: That Should say pull not kill sorry - on phone, autocorrect!!

Comment: I need to dump the values into a csv

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your dataset is structured as:

```
(pprint ds)

[{:measure-value-sets
  [{:bvalue "0", :benchmark "EUR.EONIA.6Y"}
   :dimensions                                ; A symbol on its own. Really ?!?
   [{:dvalue "EUR", :type "Currency"}
    {:dvalue "21.59999999999811", :type "ValueUnderlying_0"}]]}
 {:measure-value-sets
  [{:bvalue "-0", :benchmark "EUR.6M3M.5Y6M"}
   :dimensions
   [{:dvalue "EUR", :type "Currency"}
    {:dvalue "13.199999999998733", :type "ValueUnderlying_0"}]]}]
```

You can get all the bvalues with:

```
(map #(-> % :measure-value-sets first :bvalue) ds)
```

And your second dvalues with:

```
; highly unlikely your structure is correct
(map #(-> % :measure-value-sets (nth 2) second :dvalue) ds)
```

And together with:

```
(map (juxt 
        #(-> % :measure-value-sets first :bvalue) 
        #(-> % :measure-value-sets (nth 2) second :dvalue)) 
  ds)
```

Which returns

```
(["0" "21.59999999999811"] ["-0" "13.199999999998733"])
```

However, I don't think the structure you supplied is correct.